# Can't relay mail server to SendGrid

Tags: sendgrid, exim

I've gone through the SendGrid integration instructions for Exim (http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/exim/)

However, any email I send now is not being sent. Its all stuck in the queue. I looked for the log file for a message I'm trying to send and this is what I get:

```
2011-10-12 19:49:14 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1RE9U2-0007Qg-20

+++ 1RE9U2-0007Qg-20 has not completed +++
2011-10-12 19:49:14 1RE9U2-0007Qg-20 <= email@example.com H=localhost [127.0.0.1] P=esmtpa A=dovecot_login:email@example.com S=731 id=20111012194913.13697j8jpb4heop5@example.com T="Test"
2011-10-12 19:49:14 1RE9U2-0007Qg-20 == email@gmail.com R=send_via_sendgrid T=sendgrid_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

I've had the support rebuild the exim db, but that hasn't helped. I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that its using the dovecot login instead of the sendgrid login which is added after it. How do I make it use the sendgrid login info? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using your *SG* credentials you're going to run into authentification issues.

Try the following to make sure you are using the correct credentials:

```
 *:sendgridusername:sendgridpassword
```